# Is Constraint Layout a replacment for all other layouts?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Should I replace all other layouts with Constraint layouts.  I heard that maybe it is encouraged to use constraint layout.  Is it because the other layouts will be deprecated soon?  I was trying to replace nested linear layouts with a constraint layout, and it seemed more difficult using a constraint than just using linear layouts since the chains just got tangled up with each other.

Comment: Constraint Layout is just a replacement for Relative Layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't and shouldn't replace all other layouts with ConstraintLayouts :) Many  standard layouts have much more cool functionality that just relative positioning of subviews - for example you can easy create animated app bar with CoordinatorLayout, but you'll spend much more time to implement this manually with help of ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely Not.

Constraint layout provides more flexibility than relative layouts. So it's an improved version of relative layout (and in some cases linear layout too.).

It works on **Flat Hierarchy Model**, so it can be of help when you have a view that is nested and complex. Constraint layout will have better performance than nested relative layout.

Another advantage is **UI Responsiveness** that can be achieved via constraints. So the UI automatically adjusts to the screen. This has been a challenge for developers for a long time trying to create identical look and feel for various resolutions/ screen-sizes. The feature that was missing in relative layouts.